# Discord.js How can i get guildMember's avatar url? NOT: This event is 'guildMemberAdd'

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

```
client.on('guildMemberAdd', (guildMember) => {
     console.log(guildMember.avatarURL);
}
```

I tried that but it turned 'undefined'. How can i get guildMember's avatar url?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `avatarURL` method is only available on the `User` property of the GuildMember.
Also it in an Method so it would be something like `guildMember.user.avatarURL()`

https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/User?scrollTo=avatarURL

Comment: So this helped you out? Yay! Have funs with building your Discord Bot!

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this method was already available in April 2020 when Kawaaii answered your question. But the `GuildMember`-object ***does* have** a method called [`avatarURL()`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/discord.js/stable/class/GuildMember?scrollTo=avatarURL). It returns a string containing the discord-url to the members avatar or null if the member has not set an individual avatar for the server.

So as an example from an [`interaction`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/discord.js/stable/class/Interaction) you could get it like so:

```
const memberAvatarURL = interaction.member.avatarURL()
```

Since as mentioned this method can return null, you can uses the member's regular avatar as fallback:

```
const memberAvatarURL = interaction.member.avatarURL() ?? interaction.member.user.avatarURL()
```

With both methods you can also pass along [`ImageURLOptions`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/discord.js/stable/typedef/ImageURLOptions). The following will give you a link to the member's avatar with a size of 1024px and of the image-type jpg:

```
const memberAvatarURL = interaction.member.avatarURL({size: 1024, format: 'jpg'})
```